# How to delete continuous four digits from a column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
col1         col2                col3
 A        12134 tea2014           2
 B        2013 coffee 1           1
 C        green 2015 tea          4
```

I want to remove where the digits occurring for exact four times

The result will look like:

```
 col1         col2                col3
 A        12134 tea                 2
 B         coffee 1                 1
 C        green tea                 4
```

What is the best way to do it using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need `str.replace` with a carefully applied regex pattern:

```
# Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew for the improvement!
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)', '')
df

  col1        col2  col3
0    A   12134 tea     2
1    B    coffee 1     1
2    C  green  tea     4
```

**Regex Breakdown**
The pattern `(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)` will look for exactly 4 digits that are not preceeded by digits before or after (so strings of less/more than 4 digits are left alone).

```
(
    ?<!   # negative lookbehind 
    \d    # any single digit
)
\d{4}     # match exactly 4 digits
(
    ?!    # negative lookahead
    \d
)
```

Comment: that is some kicka** regex. :O also +1 for the breakdown

Comment: @anky_91 Huh, if that impressed you, you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53915214/4909087)...

Comment: yeah, speechless already. :D

Comment: @coldspeed what if the string starts with continuous five digits then I want to drop first four digits and take the fifth one ? for example 12345abc will be replaced by 5abc

Comment: `r'((?<=\D)|(?<=^))\d{4}(?=\D|$)'` = `r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)'`. This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532970/3832970

Comment: @KallolSamanta You can use `((?<=\D)|(?<=^))\d{4}`.